# How to Display External Image URLs on WordPress List Pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I am fetching image URLs from another website in WordPress and saving them in a custom field. I want to display these images on　the listing page, similar to YouTube thumbnails. As I want to avoid using WordPress' 'Featured Image' that requires image uploads, could you guide me on how to achieve this?

I've tried various things such as shortcodes, plugins, and theme customization, but none of them worked successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should preface this by explaining that displaying images from other websites on your own website is a bad idea. Even if you don't host the images directly, unless you own those images you're likely violating copyright. The rest of the answer assumes that you own the right to use those images.

As the Featured Image is a part of the core WordPress functionality, it's easy to use and supported by most plugins, so if you can use it, I suggest that you do.

Depending on how you store the custom fields (Advanced Custom Fields, etc), you may already have the option to display those on your site in a variety of ways, and you should check the documentation for those plugins.

Regardless, for the most part, if you want to store an image URL as a string, then it will require some coding on your part to display it as an image within your query loops.

A shortcode is often the simplest way to do so:

```php
add_shortcode('display_external_image', 'display_external_image');
function display_external_image($attr, $content = null) {
    // Assumes this shortcode is called within a WordPress loop
    $url = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'external_image_url', true);
    if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
        return sprintf('<img src="%1$s"/>', $url);
    }
}
```

And then you can put your shortcode within the loop by outputting `[display_external_image]`.